# What is a PHP code generator?

Tags: php, code-generation

I'm thinking of using a php cms, a php framework or php code generator. A php cms is restricted somehow and with a php framework and a php code generator I have more freedom. But what exactly is the difference between a framework and a code generator or what do a framework share with a code generator? I'm also planning to use Scriptcase 5 for a project because I already have the licence and I don't want to use a cms or something similiar that can limit me.

Comment: its your wish, you can choose what have more `freedom` and `features` too

Comment: The better question is: What they have in common? A framework is a framework and a code generator is a generator for code.

Comment: @KingCruch: What do they have in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMS, framework and PHP code generator are three different beasts.

CMS is a software tool tailored to allow easy website editing/maintenance. Most CMS use databases though there are file-based ones as well. Popular CMS are Joomla, Drupal, CMSMS and Wordpress to some extent. You can use CMS to maintain your website however building a web application like Twitter or Facebook won't be possible. CMS is not a tool, this a web application.

Both framework and PHP code generator allow you to build web applications. With framework you still need to write the actual code. PHP code generator will generate 50-90% of code for you.

Lets use an analogy. You need to build a car. Writing code manually means building a car from scratch: building your engine, your transmission, writing the software for car computer etc. It will take many man years to build one.

Using framework is similar to buying DIY kit. You get engine, body, wheels and just need to assemble it. Depending on your skills this can take up to few months.

Using PHP code generator is similar to pronting your car on 3D printer. You choose the program, select make/model/options and click 'Print'. Some time later you have your car. You might be able to customize it to some extent. You can even buy another engine and replace the stock one.

And CMS is the car. You can paint it different colors, change wheels etc. If you need another car, you have to get another CMS.

If you read that far you deserve to know that the best PHP code generator on the market is [PHPRunner](http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/index.htm).

Answer (score 4):

With a code generator such as Scriptcase, you do not have to write PHP / HTML code to create a data-driven web application.

However, if you want to extend the default features of the web application generated by a code generator, this will be painfull and you must have both time and deep understanding on how PHP and the generated code works.

- If you want to create a website/blog/publication web app => use an existing CMS (do not re-invent the wheel)

Otherwise:

- If you don't have the time and/or you don't know how to develop a web application => use a code generator
- If you want to create a complex web application => learn how to develop (if needed) and use a framework

Comment: I'm totally new to Scriptcase and I'm used to a cms and I can do a lot of things with it. Do you mean a code generator is even more limited?

Comment: It does not create the same type of website. I would say that a CMS creates a web*site* whereas a code generator create a basic web*application* used to manage data with CRUD features (Create/Read/Update/Delete).

Answer (score 0):

Code generators are best to develop Database management systems. They save you lot of efforts in writing lengthy code for almost similar tasks. Some of the Code Generators do amazing work for you with just few clicks.
Also maintaining the project becomes very easy with these generator for everyday customers requirements

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Scriptcase if you want a make simple projects with cruds and so on. For complex project you will need more flexibility and Scriptcase doesn't flexible. I worked with Scriptcase for 7 years and it's amazing.